# How to debug SSH tunneling web server behind LAN?

Tags: lan, putty, port-forwarding, webserver, ssh-tunnel

I am currently trying to access a Redmine server we have at the lab I work in at the university. After some research I found out it was possible to do so through SSH tunneling, and actually got it to work for a brief moment yesterday night by following the guidelines in [this](http://chamibuddhika.wordpress.com/2012/03/21/ssh-tunnelling-explained/) and [this](http://www.silvertree.org/smtp_tunnel.htm) pages.

I am not able to do it anymore, though, so I get the feeling either I am missing out on something or somehow my traffic is being blocked by the university firewall. Is the second option possible if I am still able to SSH to my lab server?

Here's my network setup (Lab Server is behind the university firewall, which restricts access to several ports, but allows SSH access):

> `Home --(SSH)--> Lab Server --(LAN)--> Redmine server`

I am using Windows 7 and my SSH tunnel is configured through [PuTTY](http://www.putty.org/). I changed my Proxy settings in Google Chrome using the [TunnelSwitch extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tunnelswitch/nfpphleklkamlblagdkbkomjmaedanoh?hl=en).

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can debug my SSH tunnel and get my setup to work again (or find out whether I have to talk to the university network admins...)?

Thanks for the attention!

**EDIT:** I had set up the SSH tunnel to port-forward source port `3128` to `[RedmineServerHost]:80`. `[RedmineServerHost]` is solvable only within the lab LAN, by our local DNS server ([dnsmasq](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html)). I just realized I am able to access the Redmine server simply by entering `localhost:3218` in my browser, regardless of whether I change my proxy settings in Google Chrome.

This means my access is not being denied by the university firewall or anything like that. Good.

While this solves many of my problems, I was looking for a cleaner solution where I simply enter `[RedmineServerHost]` in the browser and it is able to open the correct page. I had this working yesterday!

Comment: Can you access the redmine server from the Lab Server console (via ping, curl and/or lynx)?

Comment: I am not sure if I completely understand your question, but once I am logged in the Lab Server I am able to SSH the machine that had the Redmine server running. I can also wget the login page for the Redmine server from the console.